# Grails - Spring Security not working with Mysql 8

Tags: java, mysql, spring, grails

I have a application where I used these technologies:

- Grails 3.3.0
- JDK 1.8
- Spring 4+
- Mysql 8
- GORM 6.1.6.RELEASE
- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0
- Hibernate 5+

Problem is when I am trying to connect the application with Mysql 8(with 5.6+ it is working fine), I am not able to get the information related to user from Grails-Spring-Security plugin.
The application is running even connect to DB but wont be able to authenticate or fetch the information of the User like findByUsername where username is property in my user domain class.

I have User domain class defined in application.properties file.

> grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.aaa.User'

At some point I found this error but not sure whether it is related to this or not.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Either class [com.aaa.User] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. 
Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.
```

Want to understand why it wont be able to fetch the information from DB. I have tried lot of things like change the GORM version to 6.1.7 and grails spring-secuirty-core plugin version but not able to get anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Atul

Comment: have you upgraded the db driver?

Comment: Yes, upgraded it to **mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17**

Comment: turn `logSql` on and analyze the log messages during start-up. That `IllegalStateException` is a consequence of a bigger problem happenned before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to solve the issue. It happens when grails-hibernate plugin look for the property(in my case its **username** as I am calling API findByUsername) which is present in the static api or not. If it is not there it throws the exception.

The thing worked for me is, I have to put the property in static mapping of **User** domain class:

```
static mapping = {
table 'userTable'
id column: 'id'
password column: 'userpassword'
username column: 'username'
}
```

I am not sure why it is happening, when I run the application with Mysql5.6+ its working.(The driver is according to it) but when go with Mysql8, it look for the property in static mapping.

One more point I would like to mention to fix the issue is, make sure you have tablename, columnname same as defined in DB. **Case sensitivity is what expected.**

As I mentioned the case sensitivity, if you are using linux with Mysql8, the **lower_case_table_names=0**, this check with the following as per Mysql official documentation:

> Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase
>   specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement. Name
>   comparisons are case sensitive. You should not set this variable to 0
>   if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file
>   names (such as Windows or macOS). If you force this variable to 0 with
>   --lower-case-table-names=0 on a case-insensitive file system and access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index corruption
>   may result.

So if the table name is static is in camel or upper case and in db it is lower case it wont match. and the error occurred.

Hope this helps to someone.